# Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions with the sup norm. Show that $\varphi:C[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}, \varphi(f) = f(a)$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Let $C[a,b]$ be the set of continuous functions from $a$ to $b$ with the sup norm $d(f,g) = \sup\{|f(x)-g(x)| : a\leqslant x\leqslant b\}, f,g \in C[a,b]$. Show that $\varphi:C[a,b] \to \Bbb{R}, \varphi(f) = f(a)$ is continuous.

I'm lost on how to show this. This seemed easy at first, but I cannot find any definition to use here. $\varphi$ eats continuous functions and outputs the continous function evaluated at $a$, but how can I show this rigorously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\varepsilon$ and then\begin{align}\|f-g\|<\delta&\iff\sup_{x\in[a,b]}\bigl|f(x)-g(x)\bigr|<\varepsilon\\&\implies\bigl|f(a)-g(a)\bigr|<\varepsilon\\&\iff\bigl|\varphi(f)-\varphi(g)\bigr|<\varepsilon.\end{align}